# R: Find non-similar columns for records of interest in dataframe

Tags: r

Out of the total records, I have 225 duplicated records of two columns (parent_mol_chembl_id, parent_name) in a dataframe called test3333 (2859 observations with 4734 columns).

```
  parent_mol_chembl_id  parent_name  D000022 D000038 D000152 D000166
  CHEMBL1502            PANTOPRAZOLE    0       0       0    0
  CHEMBL1502            PANTOPRAZOLE    0       0       0    1
  CHEMBL790             DZOLE           0       0       1    1
  CHEMBL790             DZOLE           0       0       0    1
```

I want to find out which columns are different in the duplicated rows.
I do this `grep('CHEMBL1502', test3333[,1])` and then I inspect different column range for identifying the difference.

> Desired output for `grep('CHEMBL1502', test3333[,1])`

```
  parent_mol_chembl_id  parent_name   D000166
  CHEMBL1502            PANTOPRAZOLE    0
  CHEMBL1502            PANTOPRAZOLE    1
```

> Desired output for `grep('CHEMBL790', test3333[,1])`

```
  parent_mol_chembl_id  parent_name   D000152
  CHEMBL790             DZOLE           1   
  CHEMBL790             DZOLE           0
```

I want to find out which column names are different in the dataframe for a particular parent_mol_chembl_id? Kindly let me know what is the syntax to check for the different column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `split` by the first two columns and then `Filter` the columns based on the `length` of `unique` elements in the column.  We delete the columns that have only a single `unique` element

```
lapply(split(df1, df1[1:2], drop=TRUE), function(df) 
         Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))>1|!is.numeric(x), df))
#$CHEMBL790.DZOLE
#  parent_mol_chembl_id parent_name D000152
#3            CHEMBL790       DZOLE       1
#4            CHEMBL790       DZOLE       0

#$CHEMBL1502.PANTOPRAZOLE
#   parent_mol_chembl_id  parent_name D000166
#1           CHEMBL1502 PANTOPRAZOLE       0
#2           CHEMBL1502 PANTOPRAZOLE       1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(parent_mol_chembl_id = c("CHEMBL1502", "CHEMBL1502", 
"CHEMBL790", "CHEMBL790"), parent_name = c("PANTOPRAZOLE", "PANTOPRAZOLE", 
"DZOLE", "DZOLE"), D000022 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D000038 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), D000152 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), D000166 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L)), .Names = c("parent_mol_chembl_id", "parent_name", "D000022", 
"D000038", "D000152", "D000166"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the indices of duplicated first column ids and

```
  mydata <- test3333  
    uniqueIds = as.character(mydata[duplicated(as.character(mydata$parent_mol_chembl_id)),1])#unique(as.character(mydata$parent_mol_chembl_id))
        for(i in 1:length(uniqueIds))
        {
          print(uniqueIds[i])
          testIds = uniqueIds[i]
          index = which(testIds==mydata[,1])
          tmp=mydata[index,]
          countX = apply(tmp,2,function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])))
          length(which(countX!=1))
          table(countX)
          indexDiff=which(countX>1)
          if(length(indexDiff)==1)
          {
            t=as.matrix(tmp[,indexDiff])
            colnames(t)=colnames(tmp)[indexDiff]
            print(t)
          }else{
            print(tmp[,indexDiff])
          }

        }
```